# How do I get the changed element in a multiselect, using KendoUI?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a multiselect-list that acts as holder for a list of tags. I can't seem to figure out how to *properly* get the value of the item being changed and passed along with the changed-event. Here's my Kendo multiselect:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
          .Name("tags")
          .Placeholder("No tags selected for this unit")
          .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.TagsAvailable))
          .Events(e => e
                    .Select("select")
                    .Change("change"))
          .Value(Model.TagsSelected.ToArray())
          )
```

And here are my js-methods:

```
        function select(e) {
            var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[e.item.index()];
            var param = dataItem.Text;
            var url = '/UnitDetails/TagUnit/@Model.UnitId';

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { selectedItem: param },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    // ...
                },
                error: function () {
                    // ...
                }
            });
        };

        function change(e) {
            var dataItem = this;
            var param = dataItem.element.context.innerText;
            var url = '/UnitDetails/UnTagUnit/@Model.UnitId';

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { selectedItem: param },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    // ...
                },
                error: function () {
                    // ...
                }
            });
        };
```

My problem beeing that I feel the assignment of param is just quick and dirty. Surely, there must be some other, more correct way of going about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no easy way (afaik) for knowing the changes. So, let do it by ourselves.

First, I'm going to save the old value using the following function.

```
function saveCurrent(multi) {
    multi._savedOld = multi.value().slice(0);
}
```

Where `multi` is the multi-select that we pass to the function as argument (so you can use the function for multiple `multiselects`).

Then, you need to implement `change` as follow:

```
change    : function (e) {
    // Retrieve previous value of `multiselect` saved using previous function
    var previous = this._savedOld;
    // These are current values.
    var current = this.value();
    // Let's save it for the next time
    saveCurrent(this);

    // The difference between previous and current are removed elements
    var diff = $(previous).not(current).get();
    console.log("removed", diff);

    // The difference between current and previous, are added elements
    diff = $(current).not(previous).get();
    console.log("added", diff);
}
```

Running example here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/MapVN/

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer OnaBai! very useful and helpful.

I had the same Nickla's problem.
But, I needed to "save current values" at dataBound event. And it works (logging the changed values).

If you start deleting an item, it fails because the function recognizes the "change" as an "item add".

This is what I did

```
function dataBound(ev) {

        saveCurrent(this);
    }

    function saveCurrent(multi) {
        multi._savedOld = multi.value().slice(0);
    }

    function change(ev) {


        var previous = this._savedOld;

        var current = this.value();

        saveCurrent(this);

        var diff = $(previous).not(current).get();
        console.log("removed", diff);

        var removedSkill = diff;

        console.log("removedSkills", removedSkill);

        diff = $(current).not(previous).get();
        var addedSkill = diff;
        console.log("added", diff);
        console.log("addedSkills", addedSkill);

        if (addedSkill.length > 1 || removedSkill.length > 1) {

            if (addedSkill.length > 1) {

                addedSkill = addedSkill[addedSkill.length - 1];
                alert("Added skill code: " + addedSkill.toString());
            }

            if (removedSkill.length > 1) {
                removedSkill = removedSkill[removedSkill.length - 1];
                alert("Removed skill code: " + removedSkill.toString());
            }
        }
        else {
            if (addedSkill.length > 0) {
                alert("Added skill code: " + addedSkill.toString());
            }
            if (removedSkill.length > 0) {
                alert("Removed skill code: " + removedSkill.toString());
            }
        }


        $.ajax({
            url: "SomeUrl",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ removedSkill: removedSkill, addedSkill: addedSkill })
        });
    }
```

Thanks again!

Iván